# unobstrusive ajax call not reaching onfailure, statuscode output in console instead

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

I am using ajax unobtrusive and when it gets to my custom authorization tag the status code is set and I have json data ready to go but when its returning the information the status code is caught in the console and saying for example,"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403(forbidden)."  I placed alerts in the onfailure ajax option and nothing is being fired there. It seems its not considering a statuscode error as a failure ajax call.  How can I handle the status code error in the onFailure ajax option?

```
                    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                    filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
                    {
                        Data = new
                        {
                            Error = "NotAuthorized",
                            LogOnUrl = urlHelper.Action("AccessDenied", "Error", new { area=""})
                        },
                        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    };
                }
```

This is in my custom authorize attribute.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Company", "Company", "Admin", null, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "centerAdmin", HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "Oncomplete", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" })
```

my Ajax unobtrusive call

```
<script>

function OnSuccess(ajaxContext)
{
    alert("dfgsdfgsdfgsdfgfdgsdfgddf");
}
function OnFailure(ajaxContext) {
    alert("dfgsdfsdfgdfgsgsdf");
}
function Oncomplete(ajaxContext) {
    alert("dfgsddfffffffffffffffffffffgsdf");
}
```

simple alerts to see if it fired any of these events.

Comment: Is it ever hitting any of your handlers? Like does it every hit OnSuccess or OnComplete?

Comment: It hits OnComplete with no problem

Comment: It hits OnComplete without hitting OnSuccess?

Comment: on a normal case I only use OnComplete, but ever since I modified the customauthorize attribute to handle ajax calls, it hasnt handled onFailure at all

Comment: Is the result of the ajax request actually a 403? It should hit your failure function as long as the status is in the 400s or 500s. You should be able to see the status in your debugger after the request is complete.

Comment: I see the status codes in the console but I dont see anything alerts popping on the onfailure events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr) {
    debugger;
    if (xhr.status == 403) {
        alert("403");
    }
    alert("not 403");
});
```

});

After researching a bit, I came across this code snippet which seems to solve my issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are probably tired of me answering your questions with more questions, here is something to try. It should at least fall in to your OnFailure handler. Instead of setting your Result to a json object, set it to an HttpStatusCodeResult.

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "You are not authorized to access this page!"); // Set whatever status code is appropriate.
```

Not sure about passing the logon url or other json parameters, but this should be a start. I don't think you need to set the status code of the response.

Comment: I see the result in the console.  I want to handle the 400s or 500s in the onfailure event